# Stop wordpress from redirecting to port 8000

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I'm completely new to deployment and wordpress specifically, so my question and explanation might seem dummy. But I really need help with this, searching Google didn't help. So any way, I have this host, where I installed Wordpress, and db was created automatically. I added al the content through wp-admin panel, so I won't break any connections among files by uploading my local wp files. And when I tried to open the website itself, it was **redirected to port 8000**. The only place I found this port in was db, where links to media look like http://0.0.0.0:8000/wp-content/... , but in the wp-admin panel in the media section links look fine, so I assume it is replaced somewhere. But still I can't figure out where does this port 8000 come from. Any ideas?

Comment: hello can you access the wp-admin?

Comment: @VasimVanzara yes,  I can.  I added all the content through it.

Comment: Just go to Setting->genral in admin panle.did you find path overthere you can change and update.That's it

Comment: @VasimVanzara In settings url is correct, but it still redirects.

Comment: it just for media right??

Comment: 8000 is in your localhost right?

Comment: @VasimVanzara no. What I meant was that in db port 8000 is used only in links to media and nowhere else. Redirection is when I'm trying to display the whole website. And it is not on the localhost.

Comment: can you please give me website url?

Comment: do you have redirection plugin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Step To follow after migration :**

Change site and home url from wp_option table.

Login to admin and change paramlinks from setting->paramlink choose custome and save

Use url update plugin incase some url are not updated yet.

**Try Private Browser** to check your website.Some time cache will be issue.

Right url in inspect :
[image]

Comment: "ERROR: Something may have gone wrong. 
Your URLs have not been updated.

Why do the results show 0 URLs updated?
This happens if a URL is incorrect OR if it is not found in the content. Check your URLs and try again."

So I assume it is not in the content.

Comment: just do one thing

Comment: just goto your database and search image and modify path with current site url

Comment: can you send me your website url?

Comment: damn... it does work in incognito... and I figured out why the links to some pics where http://0.0.0.0:8000/... - I was dumb enough to copy/paste post content along with images from my local project. I guess it's the cache issue than... Anyway, thanks a lot :) You guided me into the right path.

Comment: wordpress related issue always welcome.Thanks appreciation.

Answer (score 0):

## Solution with no plugins

Lets assume your wordpress site you deployed is not able to display and therefore you cant use fancy plugins for URL replacement. In that case:

1. Make `.sql` export from your database and name it `db_export.sql`
2. run `cat db_export.sql | sed s_localhost:8000_example.com_g > db_import.sql`
3. Replace data in your database by newly created `db_import.sql`

## HTTPS

In case you are going to run your deployed website on `https` instead of `http`, consider running another unix script in command line:

`cat db_import.sql | sed s_http://example.com_https://example.com_g > db_import_final.sql`

and replace data in your database by `db_import_final.sql` file we newly created.

## Wordpress still keeps redirecting...

- If this is the case, open file `wp-config.php` in your root directory
- Above line `require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-settings.php' );` enter following:

```php
define( 'WP_HOME', 'https://example.com' );
define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'https://example.com' );
```